# NSPanel not showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have created class  `ToolPanelController` subclass of `NSWindowController` and .xib file named ToolPanel but when i start my app ToolPanel don't show up. File's Owner class set up to ToolPanelController panel is delegate to file's owner and window is connected to File's owner. 
how can i set this panel to show up when my app starts running?

ToolPanelController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ToolPanelController : NSWindowController

{
    IBOutlet NSPanel *ToolPanel;
}
+ (id)sharedToolPaletteController;
@end
```

ToolPanelController.m:

```
#import "ToolPanelController.h"

@interface ToolPanelController ()

@end

@implementation ToolPanelController

+ (id)sharedToolPaletteController {
    static ToolPanelController *sharedToolPaletteController = nil;

if (!sharedToolPaletteController) {
    sharedToolPaletteController = [[ToolPanelController allocWithZone:NULL] init];
}

return sharedToolPaletteController;
}

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{

    self = [self initWithWindowNibName:@"ToolPanel"];
    if (self) {
        [self setWindowFrameAutosaveName:@"ToolPanel"];
        [(NSPanel *)[self window] orderFront:self];
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{

    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

@end
```